# Error al imprimir mediante conexion bluetooth en Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, bluetooth

Hola amigos estoy usando un paquete para imprimir vía bluetooth, el paquete funciona bien, escanea, se reconecta y se conecta con la impresora, pero al momento de imprimir no imprime y devuelve este error en la consola, consultar a poco sobre la web, pero no pudo encontrar una solución.
El complemento es: **https://pub.dev/packages/esc_pos_bluetooth**

¿Alguien ha podido imprimir con este u otro complemento y / o resolver este error?
Por favor, necesito tu ayuda.

Estoy utilizando este codigo de ejemplo que brinda el plugin:
**https://github.com/andrey-ushakov/esc_pos_bluetooth/tree/master/example/blue**

Aclarar nuevamente que me funciona la conexion y me detecta las impresoras.
El error me aparece justo al momento de prepararse para imprimir, al parecer se desconecta y no procede con la impresión.

Estoy usando una impresora: **Zebra ZQ320**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola, deberías proporcionar código para que todos puedan entender mejor el motivo de tu pregunta.

Comment: Ya actualice mi publicacion

Comment: https://github.com/andrey-ushakov/esc_pos_bluetooth/issues/5
A ver si esto te ayuda

Comment: Gracias pero no me a ayudado, creo que es en realidad este: https://github.com/andrey-ushakov/esc_pos_bluetooth/issues/99 pero tampoco existe alguna solución respecto a esto.